# I got this shirt for 10% off, I got this shirt 10% off

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, spoken-english

If a person gets 10%off on a shirt, then what is the most natural way out of the two below:

> 1.) I got this shirt 10% off.
>
> 2.) I got this shirt **for** 10% off.

I guess #1 doesn't sound natural whereas #2 does. So what do you think? Does #1 sound natural? Is it common?

Comment: The body of your question doesn't quite match the title.  Are you asking about "10% off" or "off 10%"

Comment: Sorry for the discrepancy @James K . I've edited the title....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the preposition when talking about prices or when you make an exchange:

> I got this for 10% off
>
> I got this for £40
>
> I got this medal for winning the race

Comment: So #1 sounds wrong, right?